# Crazy behavior in loop c# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, foreach

I have a really strange behavior in one of my view models.

First, in this directory I have three csv files. When I start debugging first it goes inside the foreach and then it goes to the first line `this.allDatabases.Add(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(item));` and some strange behavior happens in the next step, it goes to the view. I need to get the name of the files and add them in a collection. In another class this method is working good, but now it is just ... I don't know.

For more information, I used Visual Studio 2015 Community and .NET Framework 4.6

I don't have any exceptions. The FileConstants.PATH_TO_DATABASE is a directory, and I have three csv files on it. For a better explanation I will show two pictures.

First

[image]

and next step of debug is

[image]

**And my code:**

```
private ObservableCollection<string> allDatabases;

public IEnumerable<string> AllDatabases
    {
        get
        {
            foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(DirectoryPath, "*.csv", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
            {
                this.allDatabases.Add(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file)); // after first add is go in view and not return back in foreach loop
            }

            return this.allDatabases;
        }
    }
```

And the view

```
<Window x:Class="Growthanalyzer.App.Views.Dialogs.NewView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Growthanalyzer.App.Views.Dialogs"
    xmlns:vms="clr-namespace:Growthanalyzer.App.ViewModels.Dialogs"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="New" Height="300" Width="300">
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <StackPanel.DataContext>
        <vms:NewViewModel />
    </StackPanel.DataContext>

    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding AllDatabases}" MinHeight="150" Width="250" />
</StackPanel>
```

I don't really know what is happening and what is the problem. If any more information is needed just ask me.

How can I fix this bug, and from what is possible to receive this bug?

Comment: Whoever upvoted the question, would you mind adding information if OP have any exceptions and what is value of `PATH_TO_DATABASE`?

Comment: So when you're not running in the debugger, what happens? What is the type of `allDatabases`, and is it bound in your view? Which view is that?

Comment: This looks like a debug information issue. It's either out of date or corrupted somehow.

Comment: @JonSkeet allDatabases is ObservableCollection<string> and is nothing happens. I want to add name of files in this collection but is return when is not finish with this foreach.

Comment: Right, the fact that it's an observable collection is almost certainly relevant. My guess is that it's bound in your view, so modifying the collection will trigger a UI update. That may well be why you're seeing it step "into" the view code.

Comment: @JonSkeet OK but after that is not finish foreach statement. I have this foreach in another viewModel and is working good, but here is just not working.

Comment: Well basically we don't have enough information to reproduce this, which makes it very hard to help you. We only have tiny bits of information, we don't know how anything is bound, we don't know what thread this is running in, etc. If you could create a [mcve] it would be much easier to help you.

Comment: Where is the question ? Or what is the question ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, I think I see at least one *potential* problem (and definitely code to be avoided)...

Every time you evaluate the `AllDatabases` property, you add all the files to the collection. Property fetches shouldn't do that - they shouldn't change state.

Instead, you should populate the collection *once* (e.g. in the constructor) and then your `AllDatabases` property should just return a reference to the collection - quite possibly typed as `ObservableCollection<string>` as it's reasonable for clients to know that it *is* observable.

I don't know for sure whether that will fix the problem, but I can easily understand that binding a property which modifies the collection every time it's accessed could easily create some *really* weird behaviour.